# Reset profile settings while keeping history, bookmarks, cookies, etc

Tags: linux, firefox, firefox-profile

After updating Firefox to 40.0, the *default* profile fails to render any windows (including the menu bar and the rest of the GUI). However, I can navigate to any page, and copy page contents via the keyboard.

I've tried using `firefox --safe-mode`, but I get the same results: the window is blank as though nothing is rendering.

If I create and use a new profile via `firefox --ProfileManager`, the new profile works perfectly fine. I suspect something in *default* profile was corrupted.

How can I reset an existing profile, and retain my history, bookmarks, cookies, and ideally extension settings?

Comment: start with **firefox -safe** before really going into this.

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like I have already tried `--safe-mode`, but I got the same result.